# Objective-C - retainCount returns wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, retaincount

```
@class Person; 
@protocol PersonDelegate <NSObject> 
- (void)sendLetterForPerson:(Person *)p; 
@end 

@interface Person : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PersonDelegate> delegate; 

- (void)writeLetterComplete; 
@end

@interface TestController ()<PersonDelegate> 
    @property (nonatomic, strong) Person *per; 
@end

_per = [[Person alloc] init];
_per.delegate = self;

NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)_per.retainCount);
NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)_per.delegate.retainCount);
```

MRC create a Person object _per , set delegate , print retainCount . The _per.retainCount is one , but _per.delegate.retainCount is 12 ,why?

Comment: What is `self` in your question? What are properties of `per` in this class?

Comment: self is a controller .
`
@interface TestController ()<PersonDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) Person *per;

@end
`

Comment: ```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class Person;

@protocol PersonDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)sendLetterForPerson:(Person *)p;

@end


@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PersonDelegate> delegate;

- (void)writeLetterComplete;

@end

```

Comment: I think you should edit and add 2 above comments to your question.

Comment: <blink>
    </blink>

Comment: Different objects - different retainCount.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [official document for `retainCount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571952-retaincount).

> This method is of no value in debugging memory management issues. Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method.

I think it's not a problem if `_per.delegate.retainCount` is 12. `_per.delegate` here is a `TestController`. Maybe `viewController` references are held by another objects which are designed by default system.

For example, if `viewController` is pushed with an `UINavigationController`, `navigationController` will hold 1 reference to `viewController` and increase `retainCount` by 1.

Comment: See also my unofficial documentation for `retainCount`: http://sdarlington.github.io

Comment: Thanks .     I see .